# Hive - top n records within a group

Tags: hiveql, rank, top-n

I am currently using Hive and I have a table with the fields user_id and value. I want to order the values in descending order within each user_id and then only emit the top 100 records for each user_id. This is the code I am attempting to use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable2
CREATE TABLE mytable2 AS
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, rank (user_id) as rank
FROM 
(SELECT * from mytable
DISTRIBUTE BY user_id
SORT BY user_id, value DESC)a )b
WHERE rank<101
ORDER BY rank;
```

However when I run this query, I get the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10247]:    Missing over clause for function : rank [ERROR_STATUS]
```

FYI - My UserIds are alpha-numeric.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Add comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you have error using the rank function,
try to add `over` after rank as following:

```
....
  (SELECT *, rank (user_id) over (order by user_id) as rank
....
```

for further information how to use the rank function you could refer to this [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html#rank_unique_1)

Comment: Thank - the issue is now sorted.